# How to access array by a list of point coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have array `A = np.ones((4,4,4))` and another array that represent the coordinates of point in array **A** called **B**, lets assume that `B = [[2,2,2], [3,2,1]]`.

I tried to access A by array indexing like A[B], but it didn't works.

How i can do it in elegant way, that also work for B that it's have a higher dimensions like B of shape (10, 20, 3)  ?

Comment: 3,2,4 does not look like valid coordinates, since the highest index for a 4x4x4 is 3,3,3.

Comment: ohh sorry i corrected the example @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of coordinates, but you should *transpose* the list. Such that the items of the *i*-th dimension are passed as the *i*-th element in the indexing, for example with:

```
A[tuple(np.transpose(B))]
```

For a 4×4×4 matrix:

```
>>> A = np.arange(64).reshape(4,4,4)
>>> A
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31]],

       [[32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46, 47]],

       [[48, 49, 50, 51],
        [52, 53, 54, 55],
        [56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63]]])
```

we get for the given coordinates:

```
>>> A[tuple(np.transpose(B))]
array([42, 57])
```

and if we calculate these manually, we get:

```
>>> A[2,2,2]
42
>>> A[3,2,1]
57
```

**Background**:

`A[1,2,3]` is short for `A[(1,2,3)]` (so in a tuple). You can fetch multiple items with `A[([2,3], [2,2], [2,1])]` but then you thus first need to *transpose* the data.

Since the data is represented as `[[2,2,2], [3,2,1]]`, we thus first need to *transpose* it to `[[2,3], [2,2], [2,1]]`. Next we wrap it in a tuple, and can use this to subscript `A`.

Comment: i didn't understand something , why the items of the i-th dimension should be passed as the i-th element in the indexing ?

Comment: `A[1,2,3]` is short for `A[(1,2,3)]` (so in a tuple). You can fetch multiple items with `A[([2,3], [2,2], [2,1])]` but then you thus first need to *transpose* the data. Since right now you represent it the opposite way.